# How to install DrRacket in Kali Linux

Tags: racket

I want to Install DrRacket in Kali Linux. I send the next command

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:plt/racket

But, I receive the next message:

> aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a
>   distribution template for Kali/kali-rolling

Somebody know how to install it?

Comment: Kali linux is for penetration testing, it is not a general purpose GNU/Linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the distribution from http://download.racket-lang.org/ instead.